# A Countable Well-ordered (w.r.to usual order) subset of $\Bbb{R}$ which is not of same order type with a subset of $\Bbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> **Problem.** Let $A$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is well-ordered with respect to the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$. Then A has an order preserving bijection with a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. (**True/False**)

**My Attempt.** I progressed a little in this problem. I try to construct a counterexample to conclude the statement **FALSE**. But all the examples I figure out don't work. For example...$\{ 1/n|n \in \Bbb{N} \}\cup \{ 0\}$, $\{-1/2^n|n\in \Bbb{N} \}$..though all of them are well ordered and countable is order isomorphic to $\Bbb{N}$.

Also I can't prove the statement.

Can you please help me to conclude the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a set with order type $\omega+1$? This well ordered set is
$\{0,1,2,\ldots,\omega\}$. You need to find a sequence of reals $a_0,a_1,a_2,
\ldots$ and a further real $a_\infty$ such that (i) $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$
is a strictly increasing sequence, and (ii)
$a_\omega>a_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Can you do that?

Comment: Lord.....I choose $a_n=(1+1/n)^n$ and $a_{\infty}=e$...Does it work?

Comment: That works fine. @IndrajitGhosh

Comment: Thank you so much..@LordSharktheUnknown